# How can I stop a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, countdown

I made a countdown timer and a "Stop" button is suppose to stop the countdown and reset the textfields.

```
class Count implements Runnable {
    private Boolean timeToQuit=false;

    public void run() {
        while(!timeToQuit) {
            int h = Integer.parseInt(tHrs.getText());
            int m = Integer.parseInt(tMins.getText());
            int s = Integer.parseInt(tSec.getText());
            while( s>=0 ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ie){}
                if(s == 0) {
                    m--;
                    s=60;
                    if(m == -1) {
                        h--;
                        m=59;
                        tHrs.setText(Integer.toString(h));
                    }
                    tMins.setText(Integer.toString(m));
                }
                s--;
                tSec.setText(Integer.toString(s));
            }
        }
        tHrs.setText("0");
        tMins.setText("0");
        tSec.setText("0");
    }

    public void stopRunning() {
        timeToQuit = true;
    }
}
```

and I call `stopRunning()` when the "Stop" button is pressed. It won't work.

also, am i calling the `stopRunning()` right??

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
{
    Count cnt = new Count();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(cnt);
    Object source = ae.getSource();
    if (source == bStart)
    {
        t1.start();
    }
    else if (source == bStop)
    {
        cnt.stopRunning();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your `timeToQuit` variable `volatile`, otherwise the value of `false` will be cached. Also, there's no reason to make it `Boolean` - a primitive would work as well:

```
private volatile boolean timeToQuit=false;
```

You also need to change the condition of the inner loop to pay attention to `timeToQuit`:

```
while( s>=0 && !timeToQuit) {
    ...
}
```

You could also add a call to `interrupt`, but since your thread is never more than a second away from checking the flag, this is not necessary.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Yes, one could do it, but since OP's code checks the flag every second, all this could save you is a sub-second delay.

Comment: Got that...actually I just wanted to know whether it would be right to use Interrupt here or not..thanks!!!

Comment: @RahulTripathi Knowing that the thread must be checking the flag every second, I would probably not add a call to `interrupt()`. Had the poll interval been anything over two seconds, I'd add a call to `interrupt()`, though: my rule of thumb is that end-users tolerate sub-second delays without complaining; anything longer than a second or two gets them anxious, while five-second delays make them hit the reload button ;-)

Comment: @user2802270 That's possible. Add a label to your screen for debugging, and add `debugLabel.setText("Stopped")` to your `stopRunning()` method, and see what happens.

Comment: the "Stopped" appeared when i clicked my "Stop" button ....so i guess there's no problem with how i call?

Comment: @stringbacon Ah, I saw another issue - take a look at the update.

Comment: it still won't work though :( the countdown still continues even if i press the stop button

Comment: @stringbacon Could you post your entire code to pastebin.com and add a link in the comments?

Comment: @stringbacon That's because you keep creating a new instance of `Count` every time a user clicks a button. Make a single instance of `Count`, and use it every time through the click method. Here is a fix in pastebin: [link](http://pastebin.com/huw1RqPS).